# ignore inactive/dead nodes in knife search

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

I have a cookbook that searches for nodes using bunch of attributes, I want to eliminate dead or inactive nodes in search results. How do I go about that.

Let's say I have 4 nodes -

```
NAME  - ENVIRONMENT - STATE
node1 -    dev      -  DEAD/INACTIVE
node2 -    dev      -  ALIVE/ACTIVE
node3 -    test     -  ALIVE/ACTIVE
node4 -    dev      -  ALIVE/ACTIVE
```

I want result to be `[node2, node4]` if I `search(:node, env:dev)` instead of the result being `[node1, node2, node4]`. This is because `node1` is terminated but not cleared from node list.

I know one possible solution is to cleanup node list to not show dead nodes, but before I implement that, I'd like to have a temp or quick fix in. Is there any node attribute that tells me if a node is active/inactive or reporting to chef server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way because Chef has no concept of "inactive" or "dead". It knows the timestamp of the last node save (read: probably the time of the last successful converge unless you did something weird in your code), but that's it. There's a lot of tools out there to garbage-collect your clients and nodes based on heuristics (time since last converge, checking against AWS APIs, etc), but none is applicable to all situations.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @coderanger, really helpful. Do you have any thoughts/suggestions on node list cleanup using some script/SQS queue triggers?